# He said the tv would be on when I wake up or woke up

Tags: tense, reported-speech

What exactly is the correct from out of these:

> He said the tv would be on when I wake up

or

> He said the tv would be on when I woke up

Comment: What is your suggestion

Comment: If the speaker hasn't ***yet*** woken up (i.e. - she's speaking *before she goes to sleep*, repeating to someone else the assurance he gave her), it's ***when I wake up*** (which learners can think of as *when I **will** wake up*, even though native speakers don't actually use ***will*** to indicate "future" in such contexts). If she's speaking ***after*** having woken up, it has to be ***when I woke up***.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's easier for me to deal with reported speech when i revert the past tense to the original, present, direct speech first. In this case it's: 'TV will be on when you wake up'. Now, since you know that after 'He said (that)' there should be past tense, you covert it to 'would be on when I woke up'.

Comment: I think the direct speech use "would" since the first sentence use it.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the sentences can be used. We usually *back shift* the tense when we report a direct speech.  In this case, for example, the direct speech should be

> *"**The tv would be on when you wake up**" she said*
>
> - Reported speech : *She said the tv would on when I woke up*.

However, it is *not* necessary to back shift the tense [when expressing future actions](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech/reported-speech-indirect-speech)

So,

> *She said the tv would be on when I wake up*

Is also correct.